# How to append a div directly after an li element, even when the li's are nested

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have the following:

```
<ul>
    <li id="comment-1">
        <div class="content">some content</div>
        <ul>
            <li id="comment-3">
                <div class="content">more content</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="comment-2"></li>
</ul>
```

Each `<div class="comment">` has a reply button, I would like, directly under that div to have (appear) a reply forum which is created else where. I was thinking of using `.append()` but that appends the "what ever" after all other elements in that div, so in this case that "reply form" would come at the very end of the `li`, with nested content and some of the nesting can be rather long.

the end result should be:

```
<ul>
    <li id="comment-1">
        <div class="content">some content</div>
        <form></form> // appears when you click reply.
        <ul>
            <li id="comment-3">
                <div class="content">more content</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="comment-2"></li>
</ul>
```

I am unfamiliar with how to create this affect. Can some one please explain how this might be done and possibly link to a jsfiddle so I can play around with it to better understand the mechanics involved?

Comment: So you want the form to appear after someone clicks the reply button?

Comment: jQuery style `$('.content').after('<form></form>')`. Native style `document.querySelector('.content').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<form></form>');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this can help you:

```
$('#comment-1 > .content').after('<form></form>');
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "#comment-1>.content" ).after( "<form>hello</form>" );
```

Comment: this will append multiple `<form>` to all the `.content` classes... Use `#comment-1 > .content` selector instead, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347237/how-to-append-a-div-directly-after-an-li-element-even-when-the-lis-are-nested#24347312).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using after()?

http://api.jquery.com/after/

Comment: Working example [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347237/how-to-append-a-div-directly-after-an-li-element-even-when-the-lis-are-nested#24347312)

Answer (score 0):

use `.after()`

Here is an example:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Content can be created and then inserted after several elements at once:

```
$('.inner').after('<p>Test</p>');
```

Each inner  element gets this new content:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <p>Test</p>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

An element in the DOM can also be selected and inserted after another element:

```
$('.container').after($('h2'));
```

If an element selected this way is inserted elsewhere, it will be moved rather than cloned:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
<h2>Greetings</h2>
```